# Disabling SeekBar in Android disables decor view?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, seekbar

I have a SeekBar Widget inside a AppCompatActivity using appcompat-v7-22.1.1. If I call mSeekBar.setEnabled(false), it seems that not only the SeekBar widget gets disabled but all parent views as well up the hierarchy to the decor view. So after this call all parent views are disabled including the decor view of other Activities.

This is the weirdest issue I ever encountered on Android. Can anybody confirm this issue and tell how to solve/avoid it? It seems that this issue did not occur with appcompat 21.0.0 or 22.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for Disable seekbar Temporarily.

In Xml, Just create a layout which is visibility:GONE

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Mainlayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/seekbarblocklayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        />
    <com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....
    ....
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In Java,

```
    public void disableSeekbar{

             seekbarblocklayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.seekbarblocklayout);
            seekbarblocklayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            seekbarblocklayout.bringToFront();
    }

  public void enableSeekbar{
            seekbarblocklayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
```